# Why both onblur events of asp:textbox getting executed?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, dom-events, onblur

In my website of Visual Studio 2008 (.NET 3.5), I have two textboxes in a page and there are two different `onblur` events for both. when first event is getting executed, the same time another is also getting executed. I don't get why it is. Here is code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBK_CODE" Width="236px"
      CssClass="inp-form" MaxLength="8" onblur="javascript:SearchBK();"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSL_CODE" Width="236px"
      CssClass="inp-form" MaxLength="8"onblur="javascript:SearchSL();"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now this functions will call webservice functions, below code:

```
 function SearchBK() {
      var textInput = document.getElementById('<%=txtBK_CODE.ClientID %>');
      ValidateBKSLCode.ValidateBK_CODE(textInput.value, OnSearchCompleteBK, OnErrorBK);
      loaded = true;
 }

 function OnErrorBK(result) {
      alert(result.get_message());
 }

 function OnSearchCompleteBK(result) {
      document.getElementById('<%=lblBK_NAME.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById('<%=lblBK_NAME.ClientID %>').innerHTML = result;
 }

 function SearchSL() {
      var textInput = document.getElementById('<%=txtSL_CODE.ClientID %>');
      ValidateBKSLCode.ValidateSL_CODE(textInput.value, OnSearchCompleteSL, OnErrorSL);
      loaded = true;
 }
 function OnErrorSL(result) {
      alert(result.get_message());
 }

 function OnSearchCompleteSL(result) {
      document.getElementById('<%=lblSL_CODE.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById('<%=lblSL_CODE.ClientID %>').innerHTML = result;
 }
```

I took the labels but not writing it here. Also when I press tab key in first textbox, both `onblur` events are getting fired but when pressing tab in second, only second function executes. (Used Javascript tags also but not writing here.) This page is in masterpage and I added service reference in scriptmanager in masterpage. Strange thing is in another website the works fine...!
What am I missing or some silly mistake...?

Answer (score 0):

set asp.net textbox AutoPostBack= false and your asp.net textbox will function like an html textbox then your code should work fine